# Angular view loaded but URL changes to 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have an angular application, and I perform a state.go to a view. The view loads correctly but the url changes to a 404 (which is in my otherwise). Here is my routes file:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('404');
 .
 .
 .
 .
 myview = {
name: "myview",
url: '',
template: '<ui-view/>',
controller: function($state) {
    return $state.go(stateToGo, {}, {
      location: false
    });
  }
  };
 myviewView = {
name: 'myview.view',
url: '/myview/:param',
templateUrl: 'static/partials/myview.html',
controller: 'myviewCtrl'
 };

$stateProvider.state(myview);
$stateProvider.state(myviewView);
 .
 .
 .
});
```

when I hit localhost/#/myview/randomname , it loads up the myview partial but the URL shows to localhost/#/404.

I tried playing around with the parameters of state.go, but it always seems to do the same thing

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set an empty URl. It should either be '/' or, if this state should not be accessible via a url, not set at all. You can declare the `myview` state as abstract without one and it still gets rendered on every child-state.

```
 myview = {
    name: "myview",
    template: '<ui-view/>',
    abstract: true
};
```